# How can you merge two worlds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to download two Minecraft maps, and then put them together. Side by side, as in the builds. Like, specifically, a city, and a couple of districts or neighborhoods. How do I do it in the sense that its merged?

Answer (score -1):

You could copy one region with MCEdit and paste it in the other world.
https://www.mcedit.net/

Comment: That's the answer as found in the duplicate question. Please refrain from repeating answers as this adds no new information.